# GIMP Change color of black icon with transparent background

Tags: gimp

I have a black icon and I want to change the color of this icon with GIMP:

[image]

Now I trying to turn the black color into red:
Colors → Map → Color Exchange (From color 'black' to color 'red').
But GIMP turns the color into grey:

[image]

Can someone help me how I can avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the color mode of your image to RGB, then coloring will be possible.

Comment: And how can I change the color mode to RGB? Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: Ah yes. I found this option to change the color mode. Thank you. It works!